# What will be the optimal solution?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given `n>=0`, create an array with the pattern `{1,1, 2,1, 2, 3, ... 1, 2, 3 .. n}`.

As an example if you given `n=3`, your method should return array as `{1,1,2,1,2,3}`.

My solution is here....

```
public int[] upSeries(int n) {

    int var1 = n + 1;        
    int var2 = n;
    int var3 = (var1*var2) / 2;
    int arr_length = var3;
    int value = 1;
    int index = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[arr_length];
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < j + 1; p++) {
            arr[index] = value;
            value++;

            if (index == arr.length - 1) {
                arr[index] = n;
                break;
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        }
        value = 1;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

What will be the best solution?

Comment: Does your solution not work? If so let us know what is not working. If you are actually asking for the best solution, that is subjective and not really the point of this site.

Comment: My code is working, I am just asking for is there solution with low time complexity

Comment: Your solution is generally just fine. It is linear in the size of the output. Unless you are looking for some lazy list evaluation - there is no real improvement that you can do, except some micro optimizations.

Comment: If your solution works, this isn't the place to post this question. A better place for your question is http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is `i` in your code? If it's `n` you are talking about, then I guess, your code would not work as you expected. The problem here is the size of the array. Check it for `4`. The size comes out to be `8`, but it should be `10`.

Comment: yes i should use as n.sorry

Comment: @Ruchi.. Well, you just changed the method parameter. Inside you are still using `i`. Anyways, the size of your array will not come out correct. Please check that.

Comment: @RohitJain: There is nothing to do with the variable name, I agree it is bad practice. It fails for input 4 (and any odd input) due to integer arithmetics. (`(4+1)/2 == 2`)

Comment: now i did some modification to my code and now previous issues not there.

Comment: @Ruchi. Yeah, it's fine now.

Comment: There is also a bizare edge case when `n==46341`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @Ruchi what do you think about my approach. Check my answer.

Comment: @null. Well, here's what I think. Your answer is creating a String array rather than `integer` array which OP wants. And trust, if you go to create an integer array out of it, then probably that's not a better solution.

Comment: @Rohit Jain Thanks for your idea . But he asks "method should return array as {1,1,2,1,2,3}" my one do this. May be OP has used int because n is int type. Also I changed it to char array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned it up a bit.  But its the same general idea.  You had a few redundancies that you could have removed.

```
public int[] upSeries(int i) {
    assert i >= 0;        

    int[] array = new int[(i * (i+1)) / 2)];  // Standard Sum
    int seriesnum = 1;
    int seriesmax= 1;
    for (int index=0; index < array.length; index++) {
        array[index] = seriesnum;            

        if (seriesnum++ == seriesmax) {
            seriesnum = 1;
            seriesmax++;
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

This solution is better by a constant multiple.  If you are looking for Big-Oh they are both O(i^2) and it is not possible to do better.

If you need a proof to why it is not possible to do better.  First prove that the size of the returned array is ((i) * (i+1)) /2).  Then make the argument that you have to fill every position in the array.  If you do better than O(i^2) you have not filled every position in the array.

Comment: There is also a bizare edge case when `n==46341`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @nikdeapen what do you think about my approach. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails for even inputs due to **integer arithmetics**.

For the example showed by @RohitJain, you do `(4+1)/2`, which is wrongly giving you 2. A possible solution is first multiplying `i*(i+1)`, and only later devide by 2.

---

Regarding performance:

You are running in linear time comparing to the output - with a single iteration per element, there is nothing serious that can be done, maybe only some local micro optimzations.

---

**EDIT:**

There is also an issue with the new code - a bizare edge case when `n== 46341`, the array size should be 1073720970, which is (AFAIK) theoretically possible.

However, when multiplying 46341*46342 you get out of range, which results in an **integer overflow** - and a negative size array.

This can be solved by manually checking for this case.

Comment: @amit.. OP has edited that part. So, you can edit your answer to consider any other problem if you see.

Comment: @RohitJain: There is yet another issue with a bizare edge case. Editted.

Comment: @amit.. Aw! Didn't thought of that case. I'll be giving you `+1` for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ruchi, your loop takes `O(n^2)` time - more precisely, it takes exactly `(n)(n+1)/2` time. However, since this is also the size of the array, it's not possible to do any better.

Answer (score 0):

You're for loops are just fine, there's a limit on how efficient this type of list can be to make, but your code could be cleaned up a bit. `var1` is kind of useless, `var2` is only useful if `i` is odd (otherwise it's inaccurate), and `var3` serves absolutely no function. The length of the array will be the summation of 1 to `i` or ∑`i` or `int arr_length = i*(i+1)/2`. You could even put that summation inside of your array declaration so it's easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int n =3;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String prei = "";
    for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++){
        prei    =prei + sb.append(i).toString();
    }

     char [] myArr = prei.toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> myarrayList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
public void show(int n){
for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++){
    if(n==1){
        myarrayList.add(n);
        break;
    }
    if(n>1){
        for(int j=1;j<i+1;j++){
            myarrayList.add(j);
        }
    }

}
}

public  int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
{
int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
Iterator<Integer> iterator = integers.iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
{
    ret[i] = iterator.next().intValue();
}
return ret;
}
}
```

First **Call show function and then convertIntegers**.